# How to detect from where application has started?

Tags: linux

When I type a name of some executable in command line and it starts, how can I detect path where that executable is located?

Comment: I guess your question is answered here already: 

http://serverfault.com/questions/232762/linux-how-to-know-where-a-process-was-started-and-how-it-was-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out which executable will be started by using the command

```
which <command>
```

If you want to determine the path programmatically you're on the wrong stack exchange.

Comment: If you pass option `-a`, *all* possible matches are displayed. And there is also `whereis` which searches for manuals and sources, too.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem of the simple solution

`which`*`command`* finds the executable file of the given *`command`* in your `$PATH`. Unfortunately this will not work as expected in all cases.

When *`command`* is an alias or a function, you will not get a correct result because the actual executable being run could have a completely different name. For example many Linux distributions have the `ll` alias set by default. `which ll` does not find anything. Another problematic case is when your shell behaves in a non-standard way and does not run the first *`command`* found in the `$PATH`.

### The more reliable solution

On Linux if you want to be completely sure about the path of the executable file of a running process then you can get it from its *PID* (Process ID; in the example below put the number instead of `$PID`):

```bsh
readlink /proc/$PID/exe
```

How to get the number? *PID* of the last process run in shell in background is `$!`. Small demonstration:

```bsh
sleep 20 &
readlink /proc/$!/exe
```

You can get *PIDs* of other processes for example from a process list using `ps -ef`.

Explanation: `/proc/$PID/exe` is a symbolic link to the executable file of the *running* process. The command `readlink` shows the target the symbolic link is pointing to.

### Scripts are a special case

Unfortunately the `readlink /proc/$PID/exe` method does not work as expected with scripting languages like bash, Perl, Python etc. In such cases you will get the path to the interpreter of the script (like `/bin/bash`) instead of the path to the script. To get closer to the information you can use:

```bsh
cat /proc/$PID/cmdline     # the commandline with the interpreter and script
readlink /proc/$PID/cwd    # the current working directory
```

Unfortunately the current working directory can change since the program start. Some interpreters like bash can keep the script file open on descriptor 255:

```bsh
readlink /proc/$PID/fd/255
```

### Everything can change

Any process can call `exec()` which replaces its `/proc/$PID/exe`, `/proc/$PID/cmdline` and other information.